# А существует ли хотя бы ещё одно системное число?

Tags: системы-счисления

Назовём натуральное число **системным**, если его десятичная запись не содержит цифр 0 и 1 и при этом само число является палиндромом во всех позиционных системах счисления, основаниями которых являются десятичные цифры этого числа.

Например, число 57 — системное, так как является палиндромом в системах счисления с основаниями 5 и 7.

А существует ли хотя бы ещё одно системное число?

Comment: так Вас интересует ответ да/нет? или за Вас код написать?

Comment: @KoVadim, код в данном случае вряд ли поможет. Хотя я могу ошибаться.

Comment: тогда лучше показывайте, где взяли задачу. А то иначе это выглядит очень странно.

Comment: @KoVadim, вот здесь: http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/238503/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE

Comment: ну вот среди трёхзначных чисел есть два хороших кандидата 178 (в 6 = 454, в 7 = 343, в 8 = 262) и 651
(в 5 = 10101, в 6 = 3003) но они содержат 1. Хорошей попыткой есть число 786435
(в 4 = 3000000003, в 7 = 6453546, в 8 = 3000003). А больше ничего интересного до 10 в 9. Я искал числа, которые имеют минимум 3 разных палиндрома, не исключаю, что есть числа, которые содержат одинаковые числа (типа 11111 или 2222) и они не попали в мою выборку

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы пишете: "Хорошей попыткой есть число 786435" .......... Увы, нет. Если число оканчивается на 5, то это плохая попытка, а не хорошая, поскольку "в базе 5" это число будет оканчиваться нулём.

Comment: я знаю. поэтому я и написал "хорошая попытка"

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы пишете: "не исключаю, что есть числа, которые содержат одинаковые числа (типа 11111 или 2222) и они не попали в мою выборку" ...................... Я ценю Ваше чувство юмора, но числа с нуля начинаться не умеют.

Comment: видимо я не очень удачно подобрал числа. окей, давайте посмотрим на такое 44344 (я не знаю, подходит ли число, но подозреваю, что число в таком виде может найтись. у него две разные цифры, но цифр в числе больше)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133772/discussion-between----and-kovadim).

Comment: продолжайте. я не хожу в эти чаты.

Comment: @KoVadim , 44344 оканчивается на 44, следовательно делится на 4, а значит в базе 4 оканчивается на 0.

Comment: ох. ну возьмите 43334. Оно точно на 4 и на 3 не делится